# How to work around inter-repository single file externals not supported by SVN 1.6?

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using SVN externals to include a couple of directories from another repository but I also need to set up externals for two individual files in the root of the project directory.

According to the documentation this is not yet possible:

> *The URL for a file external must be in the same repository as the URL that
>   the file external will be inserted
>   into; inter-repository file externals
>   are not supported*

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html

How can I work round this as I need two files to be pulled in from an external repository into the root of the project directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could load them using a "folder external" and move the files either with a pre-build script or maybe a tortoise svn client hook (post-update). not a great solution, but maybe good enough for you?